# django Initialising Choices in Form from Class Based View

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I've seen a lot of answers about how this is solved when not using Class Based Views. Is there some really obvious thing I'm missing about doing it with CBVs?

Basically I want to have a MultipleChoiceField in my form which has choices determined by what is happening in the view. e.g. I use the PK from the URL to do some backend requests and then those should be used to populate the choices.

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import Form, MultipleChoiceField, CharField

class EmailForm(Form):

    users = MultipleChoiceField(required=False)
    subject = CharField(max_length=100)
    message = CharField()

    def __init__(self, users=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if users:
            self.fields['users'].choices = users

#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from .views import EmailView

# url patterns
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url( r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', EmailView.as_view(), name="maindex" ),
)

#views.py
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView
from .forms import EmailForm

class EmailView(FormView):
    template_name = 'myapp/email.html'
    form_class = EmailForm
    success_ulr = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Do stuff here
        return super(EmailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Basically it boils down to how/where to call the init function from the view. How do I do that? Or is there another way I've missed? I thought of overriding `get_form_kwargs` in the view, but couldn't make that do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The view:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class EmailView(FormView):
    # ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(EmailView, self).get_form_kwargs()

        # get users, note: you can access request using: self.request

        kwargs['users'] = users
        return kwargs
```

The form:

```
from django import forms import Form

class EmailForm(Form):

    users = MultipleChoiceField(required=False)
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.users = kwargs.pop('users', None)
        super(EmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['users'].choices = self.users
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I get it now. I'd tried almost exactly this, but was getting errors about having an unexpected keyword argument in __init__. So popping it makes complete sense and now I understand it slightly better, I realised that maybe the tidiest way to do it is to have a named `users` parameter in __init__: `def __init__(self, users=None, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Ye, you can do that too. I have posted the way I do it but the other option is allright as well.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, what I've done in a similar case is the following (Python 3.5, Django 1.8):

```
def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form= super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)
    form.fields['rank'].choices= <sequence of 2-tuples>
    return form
```

where obviously `rank` is the field name. This way I use the default form.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, the FormMixin calls `get_form` to get the form-class which looks like

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    """
    Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.
    """
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

So you can either override `get_form` to instance your Form yourself

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    return EmailForm(files=self.request.FILES or None,
                     data=self.request.POST or None,
                     users=some_user_queryset)
```

or stay a bit more generic and override `get_form_kwargs` to something like

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    form_kws = super(EmailView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    form_kws["users"] = some_user_queryset
    return form_kws
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override **get_form**.

I needed to update the choices for ChoiceField based on logged in user.

Form:

```
class InteractionCreateForm(forms.Form):
    device = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(None, '----------')])
    ...
```

View:

```
class InteractionCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = InteractionCreateForm
    ...

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form_class = super().get_form(form_class=None)

        form_class.fields['device'].choices = \
            form_class.fields['device'].choices \
            + [(device.pk, device) for device in Device.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.id)]

        return form_class
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
class EmailView(FormView):
    # ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.users = ...
        return super(EmailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(EmailView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['users'] = self.users
        return kwargs
```

This allows you to set the user choices in the view and to pass them to the form.